# For any smooth manifold there exists a smooth atlas whose coordinate charts are homeomorphisms to open balls.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to show that on any smooth n-manifold $M$, there exists a smooth atlas $ \{ ( U_{\alpha},\varphi_{\alpha})\} $ such that $ \varphi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}) $ is an open ball in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ for all $\alpha$.

In the definition we used for a topological n-manifold $(M,T)$ one condition was that each $x \in M $ has a neighborhood $U \in T$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to some open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$. I did exercise 1.1 in Lee [as discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413560/basic-doubt-about-topological-manifold) which asks to show that this condition is equivalent to each point having a neighborhood homeomorphic to either $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ or an open ball in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$. I was thinking maybe this could be used to show that every $U \in T$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ and then every atlas would have the required property, but that feels wrong. Is this fact useful in obtaining my desired result?
Or is it necessary to make some use of the smoothness criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Since every smooth manifold is a topological manifold, then I would say that it is always possible to choose such an atlas.

For every $p \in M$, where $M$ is a differentiable real manifold, up to restricting the open set on the manifold, it is always possible to make the charts homeomorphic to an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$-compatibility still holds on the restriction of the transition functions.

Comment: Just a final clarification - after having constructed the required charts, we know that the collection of these charts forms an atlas, since the union of these restricted open sets on the manifold necessarily covers $M$, and we can index the collection of charts by $p \in M$ ?
Thank you!